# Call OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) from another method

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Why doesn't it work?

i got this

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{ 
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e); 
    RequestAsync( new Uri(teamsite), 
        (html, exc) => { 
             if (exc == null) { 
                 m_doc = new HtmlDocument(); 
                 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => m_doc.LoadHtml(html));
                 xpathList.Items.Add(html); 
             } 
             else { 
                 // handle exception appropriately 
             } 
         }
    );
} 

public void test()
{
    this.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
}
```

is there a way i can jump form `public void test()` to

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
```

?

Comment: that should work - what is';t working - is it not compiling? whats the compilation error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make the method call look like a method declaration.  You have to supply the argument.  Fix:

```
public void test()
{
    var arg = new NavigationEventArgs(...);  // Supply constructor arguments
    // Set arg properties if necessary
    //...
    this.OnNavigatedTo(arg)
}
```

Comment: could you tell me how you do that because i am verry new to C#

Comment: when i run it it gives this error: Error1 'System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 argument

Answer (score 1):

your code should not work because you cannot make the method call like a method declaration. You have to supply the argument

please try the below pasted code

```
public void test()
{
    var arg = new NavigationEventArgs();
    // Initialize the variable 
    // other necessory code ...

    this.OnNavigatedTo(arg)
}
```